# Is there a Migration Guide available for JBoss 4.2 to JBoss 5.1

Tags: java, jboss, migration, jboss5.x

Trying to migrate an application from JBoss 4.2 to JBoss 5.1, I face some configuration issues.

In JBoss 4.2 multiple URLs for deployment were configured in jboss-service.xml as an attribute of  mbean URLDeploymentScanner `org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner.` This mbean disappeared in JBoss 5.1. In JBoss 5.1 a new configuration file `conf/bootstrap/deployers.xml` doesn't have this bean.

Is there any resource available which descibes the changes between these server versions?

Comment: perhaps helpful for other issues: http://venugopaal.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/jboss405-to-jboss-5ga/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, someone just posted such a guide on JavaLobby

http://java.dzone.com/articles/migrating-jboss-4-jboss-5